# C++ ADO RecordSet CacheSize: how set "Maximum Open Rows"?

Tags: c++, ado

I'm trying to prevent an out-of-memory crash, ideally without having to add a scheme for paging results. The following MSDN article discusses the use of a "Maximum Open Rows" property in conjunction with the CacheSize setting to throttle the data returned by a query:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678354(v=vs.85).aspx

Sounds promising, but this is the only reference I can find, no C++ examples, and no luck coming up with a syntax that the compiler will accept. It's documented as a member of a properties collection, so I'd expect to write something like recordset->Properties["Maximum Open Rows"] = 1000 or perhaps
recordset->PutMaximumOpenRows(1000), but no dice, and Intellisense offers nothing. Can anyone out there shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page in the MSDN doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/ms675103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It suggests something like:

recordset->Properties->Item["Maximum Open Rows"]->Value = value;

Comment: Tried it and an error is thrown - I think it's a read-only property.

Comment: And here's the error: ProviderError(s): Error(1): [80040e21]:Read-only property value was not set. 

Odd, though - I can't find anything in doc to indicate that it's a read-only property, and it seems like one that should be settable, given its purpose.

Comment: Is the recordset open? Some properties have to be set after the recordset is created but before it's opened.

Comment: No, the query hasn't been issued (->Open has not yet been called).